# Is there a way to post a tuple value using mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post a two values using razer views and mvc as a tuple.

I have tried all different formatting, separating, the values by commas, by putting parenthesis and brackets angle brackets.

```
<div class="location-input">
   <input id="ElectionJsonObject.LocationPerVotingTypeDictionary[@item.Key] [@i]" type="checkbox" name="ElectionJsonObject.LocationPerVotingTypeDictionary[@item.Key][@item.Value.ElementAt(i).Key]" value="<(@item.Value.ElementAt(i).Value.Item1.ToString(), @item.Value.ElementAt(i).Value.Item2>" checked />
   <input type="hidden" name="ElectionJsonObject.LocationPerVotingTypeDictionary[@item.Key][@item.Value.ElementAt(i).Key]" value="False" />
   @Model.ElectionJsonObject.LocationPerVotingTypeDictionary[@item.Key].ElementAt(i).Key - @item.Value.ElementAt(i).Value.Item2
</div>
```

The model comes back with a null value tuple inside of that dictionary.

Comment: Is there any specific reason not to use a class?

Comment: I tried to make the value of the dictionary a class with a boolean and a string. and ``` value= "@item.Value.ElementAt(i).Value" ``` but that doesnt work the tag just spits out the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Matheus Lemos comment I used a class instead.

```
            public class LocationInformation
            {
                public string LocationDetails { get; set; }
                public bool Display { get; set; }

                //For data transfer
                public LocationInformation()
                {

                }
```

This is the class.

```
 <input id="ElectionJsonObject.LocationPerBallotTypeDictionary[@ballotType][@locationId]" type="checkbox" name="ElectionJsonObject.LocationPerBallotTypeDictionary[@ballotType][@locationId].Display" value="@locationInfo.Display.ToString()" checked />



 <input type="hidden" name="ElectionJsonObject.LocationPerBallotTypeDictionary[@ballotType][@locationId].LocationDetails" value="@locationInfo.LocationDetails"/>
```

By changing the the name to be the class values property and the value to be a single value then adding a hidden input being the other value it properly posts and the model is intact dictionary values and all.